In an isobaric system, is the change in internal energy always equal to (3/2) times the work done?
In my high school class, we are learning the basics of thermodynamics. Some of the equations we have learned are   $\Delta U = \frac {3}{2}nR\Delta T$  where $\Delta U$ is the change in internal energy, $n$ is the number of moles of a gas, $R$ is the ideal gas constant, and $\Delta T$ is the change in temperature of a gas. We also learned that $W = P\Delta V$ where $W$ is the work that a gas does, $P$ is the pressure of a gas, and $\Delta V$ is the change in volume of a gas.
In our textbook, it says that the work equation can be substituted into the change in internal energy equation for isobaric processes to get the equation $\Delta U = \frac{3}{2} W$.
So, my question is if the change in internal energy is always 3/2 times the work done by the gas in isobaric processes?
This has not been explicitly stated in our textbook and seems like it would be pretty useful if true.

Only for an ideal gas.

Only for a monatomic ideal gas.
